# Text animation: each and setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, timeout

I'm trying to animate some text. Different divs are displayed and hid one after another, so that it looks like a word is reduced to just a letter, and then completed again.

I need some sort of delay between the .each() cycles. I tried to use the setTimeOut() function, but I still see all the divs appearing and then disappearing together, instead of one by one.

```js
function fadeInOut(element) {
  $(element).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
  })
}

function displayStepWords() {
  $('.stepWord').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(fadeInOut(this), 5000 * i);
  })
}

displayStepWords();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stepWord">BYE</div>
<div class="stepWord">BY</div>
<div class="stepWord">B</div>
<div class="stepWord">BY</div>
<div class="stepWord">BYE</div>
```

Comment: `fadeInOut(this)` is processed immediately; you need to wrap it in a function. Replace it with `() => { fadeInOut(this) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear exactly what you are aiming at, but something like:

```js
function fadeInOut(element) {
  $(element).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
  })
}

function displayStepWords() {
  $('.stepWord').each(function(i) {
  var me = $(this);
    setTimeout( function(){fadeInOut(me);}, 1000 * i );
  })
}

displayStepWords();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="stepWord">BYE</div>
<div class="stepWord">BY</div>
<div class="stepWord">B</div>
<div class="stepWord">BY</div>
<div class="stepWord">BYE</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The window.setTimeout expects a function for the first parameter not a function call.

```
setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)
```

If you want to show the divs one after each other in one place - you have to add some css.

```
<style>
  .step-word {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="step-word">BYE</div>
  <div class="step-word">BY</div>
  <div class="step-word">B</div>
  <div class="step-word">BY</div>
  <div class="step-word">BYE</div>
</div>
<script>
  var delay = 500,
      $stepWords = $('.wrapper .step-word');

  function fadeInOut($element) {
    $element.fadeIn("slow", function () {
      $element.fadeOut("slow");
    });
  }

  $stepWords.each(function(i, elem) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      fadeInOut($stepWords.eq(i));
    }, delay * i);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function displayStepWords() {
 $('.stepWord').each(function(i) {
   var $el = $(this);
   setTimeout(function(){fadeInOut($el)}, 300 * i);
 })
}
```